# Do I need to specify an exe path as the 1st parameter in lpCommandLine when calling CreateProcessAsUser?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I can't seem to find a definitive answer to this. My goal is to start a process using a user token. Say, the process in question is started as such:

```
"C:\My folder\My proc.exe" param=1
```

So when I specify `lpCommandLine` parameter for the [CreateProcessAsUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429(v=vs.85).aspx) API, do I need to specify executable path as the 1st parameter as such:

```
LPCTSTR pStrExePath = L"C:\\My folder\\My proc.exe";

TCHAR buffCmdLine[MAX_PATH];
if(SUCCEEDED(::StringCchPrintf(buffCmdLine, MAX_PATH, 
    L"\"%s\" %s", pStrExePath, L"param=1")))

bResult = CreateProcessAsUser(
    hToken,            // client's access token
    pStrExePath,       // file to execute
    buffCmdLine,       // command line
    NULL,              // pointer to process SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    NULL,              // pointer to thread SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    FALSE,             // handles are not inheritable
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,   // creation flags
    envBlock,          // pointer to new environment block 
    NULL,              // name of current directory 
    &si,               // pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi                // receives information about new process
);
```

Or can I omit the exe path and do this?

```
LPCTSTR pStrExePath = L"C:\\My folder\\My proc.exe";

TCHAR buffCmdLine[MAX_PATH];
if(SUCCEEDED(::StringCchCopy(buffCmdLine, MAX_PATH, L"param=1")))

bResult = CreateProcessAsUser(
    hToken,            // client's access token
    pStrExePath,       // file to execute
    buffCmdLine,       // command line
    NULL,              // pointer to process SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    NULL,              // pointer to thread SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    FALSE,             // handles are not inheritable
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,   // creation flags
    envBlock,          // pointer to new environment block 
    NULL,              // name of current directory 
    &si,               // pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi                // receives information about new process
);
```

They both seem to work.

Comment: You don't need to include the actual path to the executable, though it is conventional to do so.  You do usually need to include *something* for the child process to interpret as the zeroth argument.  Most applications will skip over the first token, assuming that it is a module name, so in your example the `param=1` will probably be ignored.

Comment: @HarryJohnston : exactly, but again the documentation is not clear about it, saying "Because argv[0] is the module name, C programmers generally repeat the module name as the first token in the command line."

Answer (score 1):

Reading the documentation, both cases should work.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429(v=vs.85).aspx)

> If both lpApplicationName and lpCommandLine are non-NULL,
>   *lpApplicationName specifies the **module** to execute, and *lpCommandLine specifies the **command line**. The new process can use GetCommandLine to
>   retrieve the **entire command line**. Console processes written in C can
>   use the argc and argv arguments to parse the command line. Because
>   argv[0] is the module name, **C programmers generally repeat the module
>   name as the first token in the command line**.

I agree that the documentation may be clearer saying that it accepts the argument part of the command line or the full command line in `lpCommandLine` when `lpApplicationName` is non-NULL.

**UPDATE :** 
The documentation is better in the case lpApplicationName is NULL

> If lpApplicationName is NULL, the first white space–delimited token of the command line specifies the module name...

**UPDATE 2** :
There is a nice documentation about these arguments [Understanding CreateProcess and Command-line Arguments](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/175986).
Reading this documentation, I understand that there is a difference between your two cases. When you provide `lpApplicationName` and arguments in `lpCommandLine` the child process will parse the command line as it is in `lpCommandLine`. So if you do not duplicate the exe path, argv[0] will not represent the exe path as usual but param=1.

Comment: It is because of this ambiguity that I *never* use `lpApplication`: "*The lpApplicationName parameter can be NULL. In that case, the module name must be the first white space–delimited token in the lpCommandLine string.*" The complete `lpCommandLine` is passed as-is to the new process, but it can also specify which module to launch. It is not just C-based frameworks that rely on the first command line token being the module filename. Other frameworks do, too.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: So what do you use instead?

Comment: @c00000fd: You can just use the lpCommandLine parameter and pass NULL for lpApplicationName. In this case there is no ambiguity in the documentation.

Comment: @c00000fd I put the module name AND parameters in `lpCommandLine` and leave `lpApplicationName` null.

Comment: @M'handBOUGHIAS: Sorry, I just noticed your reference to [Q175986](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/175986). Man, that thing could not be more confusing. Typical Microsoft. `"This raises a potentially confusing inconsistency ..."` No sh*t! Now I need to know if it's a 16-bit vs. 32-bit process. I guess there's no more 16-bit processes out there. So that's good. But what about 64-bit processes? No mentioning of that. I hope they didn't change it there as well! So yeah, so far what RemyLebeau suggested seems to be least bug-prone.